# How to evaluate Reverse polish notation using stacks

Tags: algorithm, stack, postfix-notation, rpn

Can this postfix expression can be evaluated?

```
6 2 3 + - 3 8 2 / + * 2 5 3 +
```

Comment: Yes, and you end up with [7 2 8] on your stack (bottom to top) - the expression doesn't fully collapse since there's not enough operators. You can use `dc` to check this: `6 2 3 + - 3 8 2 / + * 2 5 3 + f` evaluates your RPN expression and dumps the stack (`f`). (But this isn't really a _programming_ question unless you are asking about code...)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming - only about the evaluation of a _particular_ RPN expression.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it can.

```
S = new empty stack
while not eof
    t = read token
    if t is a binary operator
        y = pop(S)
        x = pop(S)
        push(S, t(x, y))
    else
        push(S, t)
print the contents of the stack S
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply iterate thru entire array and:

- `push` each `number` that you meet to the stack
- if you meet `operation token` - `pop` two numbers from the stack and evaluate the operation
- `push` the result of your operation back to the stack

That's it. Complexity for this will be `linear, O(n)` for time and `linear, O(n)` for space because we use the stack to store the numbers.
The entire code using stack (`JavaScript`):

```
/*
  Function to perform operation with two numbers.
  @param {String} Operation type.
  @param {Number} Number 1.
  @param {Number} Number 2.
  @returns {Number} Result of performing the operation.
*/
var performOperation = function performOperation(operation, num1, num2) {
    switch (operation) {
        case '+': return num1 + num2;
        case '-': return num1 - num2;
        case '*': return ~~(num1 * num2);
        case '/': return ~~(num1 / num2);
        default: console.error('Unknown operation: ', operation);
    }
};
/*
  Function to check if variable holds an operation type.
  @param {Any} Token.
  @returns {Boolean} If token is string with operation type.
*/
var isOperation = function isNumber(token) {
    // map of supported operations
    var map = {
        '+': true,
        '-': true,
        '*': true,
        '/': true
    }
    return !!map[token];
};

var evaluatePolishNotation = function evaluatePolishNotation(tokens) {
  var stack = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    var token = tokens[i];
    if (isOperation(token)) {
      var number1 = stack.pop();
      var number2 = stack.pop();
      stack.push( performOperation(token, number2, number1) );
    } else {
      stack.push( parseInt(tokens[i], 10) );
    }
  }
  return stack.pop();
}
```

---

**But you can improve that by using a constant space O(1)!** Read more about the algorithm [here](https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/67582/accepted-the-best-complexity-o-n-time-o-1-space-well-explained-javascript).